# Why SpaceX is keeping it's space industry policy transparent?

Tags: spacex

SpaceX has many global competitors, both private and government funded, in the space industry. But it is following a very transparent approach during the construction and testing phases. What possibly could be the reasons behind this transparent policy?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

SpaceX is anything but transparent in the sense that they do not release technical details. Good luck trying to get **any** technical details out of SpaceX. As an example, SpaceX employees do not issue patents because patents must necessarily disclose sufficient technical details to enable a competitor to recreate the concept. SpaceX itself cannot issue patents; patents are awarded to people rather than companies.

Companies can however dictate what their employees are allowed to do. SpaceX has made it very clear to their employees that patents are, for the most part, off-limits. SpaceX views China as their ultimate competitor, and China has repeatedly shown a complete lack of regard for intellectual property rights. SpaceX is transparent only to the general public, and only for concepts that aerospace engineering students worldwide can learn shortly after they decide to become aerospace engineering students.

We have had many questions at this site asking for technical details of how SpaceX designs, builds, or operates its rockets and spacecraft. These questions inevitably go unanswered. SpaceX is extremely protective of its intellectual property, rightfully so in my opinion.

Comment: They're very open up to a point, even to a point that might be helpful to competitors, and completely closed beyond that point. For a recent example, Musk tweets freely about their experimentation in header tank pressurization strategies in the Starship prototypes.

Comment: @RussellBorogove Elon Musk at times can be SpaceX's worst enemy. (The same applies to Tesla.) He is the one person SpaceX cannot fire (or worse) for disclosing SpaceX intellectual property.

Answer (score 3):

SpaceX's "space industry policy" is not really transparent. It is more that it is obvious.

The fact that throwing away the rocket after every launch is more expensive than not throwing it away and reusing it, is not some matter of a grand "space industry policy", it is common sense: do you scrap your car and buy a new one every time you go to the grocery store, or do you use the same car over and over again?

Vertical integration is a well-known strategy that has been studied and implemented for decades in all sorts of industries … including in the automotive industry with Tesla.

And the fact that SpaceX's main goal is to colonize Mars is simply known because Elon Musk has said that long before he even founded SpaceX.